# Storing last n values for x in txt file

Tags: python, file, input

If I have a program that asks for a user's name and score, opens a .txt file, searches the file for their name like:

```
for x in f.readlines():
    if name in x.strip():
        #etc
```

If the name is found it has to edit that line and add the new score, but it must only store x number of scores, say the last 4 scores. So if 4 scores are already stored, it must delete the oldest one so as to only keep the latest 4 scores.

If the name isn't found then it's just a simple append to end of file.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: what does the file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file and put it (parse) in some kind of datastruce (e.g. a dictionary), then update the values in the dict and afterwards write it back. It may not be the most efficient way, but the way I used it most.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to figure out the format of the line. How will you separate names and scores? I'm using a comma.

```
for line in f: # readlines() is not necessary here
    if name in line:
        name, s = line.split(',', 1)
        scores = s.split(',')
        if len(scores) > 4:
            del scores[0] # remove the oldest one
        scores.append(the_new_score)
        new_line = "%s,%s" % (name, ','.join(scores))
```

And do something with new_line.

(note: this is just a very quick idea for how to accomplish this. This does not update the file in-place nor write out the results anywhere. That is left as an exercise to the reader, unless you actually need help with that part too)

Comment: Pretty elegant solution. Don't worry, I'm fine with writing to files.